# deploying from bitbucket to AWS S3, a simple static htm website

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bitbucket

So I am working on a simple stupid static website, there are not EC2 instances or anything of the sort. 
I am looking at S3 cos it can host such a website, and I am also using bitbucket (company I work for is using that ). 
Now I am trying to find away that whenever I do a git push into bitbucket, it goes all the way to the S3 bucket, I looked at the AWS pipelines here

https://bitbucket.org/awslabs/amazon-s3-bitbucket-pipelines-python?_ga=2.244703245.988359590.1519921827-876742115.1519921827

but it reuires me to upload as an artifact and add extra scripts. 
I am sure there are others who had to do this task before, is there any script I can use to trigger right after I do a git push to push it to S3?

CodeDeploy integration between AWS and bitbucket requires me at one point to have an EC2 instance, I don;t need and don;t have one , thats why I didn;t use code deploy.

Answer (score 0):

git post-commit hooks and aws cli?

https://github.com/mark-schaal/git-hooks-AWSCLI-S3

Comment: looks nice, ut sorry how do I install this? is it an npm package? how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

That's how I do it:

```
npx s3-deploy './dist/**' --cwd './dist/' --region ap-southeast-2 --bucket my-bucket-name --filePrefix bucket-folder
```

It requires npm (and node.js). It will copy only the files which do not exist in the S3 bucket.

- `npx` - the npm (>= v5) built-in command to download and execute a binary.
- `s3-deploy` - is an npm module. The rest of the arguments are passed to `s3-deploy`
- `'./dist/**'` - files you want to be copied to S3.
- The `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` + `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` env vars should exist. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html).
- More info about `s3-deploy` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-deploy

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the static web site using the following code written in bitbucket-pipelines.yml file.

```
    image: python:3.5.1
    pipelines:
      branches:
        master:
          - step:
              script:
                - pipe: atlassian/aws-s3-deploy:0.2.1
                variables:
                   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "ap-south-1"
                   ACL: "public-read"
                   S3_BUCKET: "bucket_name"
                   LOCAL_PATH: $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR 
                   #DELETE_FLAG: "true"
```

Please also setup environment variables on bitbucket pipelines AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.
Change AWS_DEFAULT_REGION to bucket region and replace bucket_name with your bucket name.
for more information watch this YouTube video [Bitbucket pipelines for deploy static website on S3](https://youtu.be/sd9r463Le48) and refer this [bitbucket Repo](https://ajay42@bitbucket.org/ajay42/clcd-demo2.git).